# eigen: how to only compute the lower/upper part in the matrix inner product

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to compute formula like "A'*A" using `Eigen` where A is an m by n matrix.  The intuitive way to do this is,

```
result = A.transpose()*A;
```

But since the result is symmetric, is it possible to only compute the lower or upper part of result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using selfadjointView and [rankUpdate](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointView.html#acc37b0437e0eee05f861bce511df9c77):

```
result.setZero();
result.selfadjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(A.transpose());
```

This will only update the lower part of `result`.